# How to conveniently do cross product of a 3x3 matrix with a 3d vector in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, cross-product

for example,

magic(3) x [1,2,3] gives:

```
-9   -18    15
 1    -2     1
23   -10    -1
```

Comment: Umm... what exactly do you mean by a cross product of a matrix with a vector?

Comment: The cross product operation is defined for pairs of 3d vectors.  You can't cross product a matrix with a vector.

Comment: I will just ignore your ignorance, jtdubs. Tensor algebra!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is compute the cross product of *each row* of a 3-by-3 matrix with a 1-by-3 vector. In order to use the function [CROSS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cross.html), the two inputs must be the same size, so you will have to replicate your 1-by-3 vector using the function [REPMAT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/repmat.html) so that it has three rows. Then perform the cross product along the columns:

```
>> A = magic(3);
>> B = [1 2 3];
>> C = cross(A,repmat(B,size(A,1),1),2);
C =

    -9   -18    15
     1    -2     1
    23   -10    -1
```